# Killed a component on Single Board Computer, SBC still functions

Tags: power, integrated-circuit, identification, failure, sbc

**Primary question upfront:** what is the general purpose of this IC, labeled "D820460". I found what appears to be the component [HERE](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/rohm-semiconductor/BD82046FVJ-GE2/846-BD82046FVJ-GE2CT-ND/10483588) on digikey.

**Background:** I have an SBC controlling tons of peripheral devices, all via USB. I'm powering these devices with my own custom power harness. I managed to swap POS/NEG power (backwards) on an externally powered USB Hub (the hub is connected to the SBC via USB). Amazingly, the hub appears unhurt, but it was connected to the SBC (via USB) and when the whole system was powered the smoke came out of the above-mentioned D820460. I fixed the harness, and the entire system, including peripherals, are all functioning normally. The component is labeled a "USB switch", so I'm beyond confident the failure was based on my power error. But why are all USB ports on the SBC still functioning? My main concern is that the blown component may be used to limit current, and that I may now have a situation where I can draw too much via USB in a high-load situation and have a safety hazard. The second concern is the system will fail prematurely. I'm strongly considering buying a new component and replacing it myself, but it still leaves me wondering, why it's there to begin with.

I apologize for the somewhat general question, I wish I could provide a schematic of the SBC.

Comment: Not really answerable. Maybe you lucked out and an ESD diode failed open instead of the normal short.

Comment: Which SBC are you using? Some have a "USB switch" circuit to control other things, like Wifi.

Comment: If your devices are self-powered rather than bus-powered they may not notice that the VBus supply from the host is dead (they should notice, but the implementation might be sloppy).  Try plugging something with LEDs on it like an unconnected USB UART board or a mouse or something into the USB port and see if it has power.  Probably you should relegate that particular example of the SBC to software work and not use it for a field deployment.

Comment: Ron Beyer, This is a System76 Meerkat. Based on your info I'll test some non-USB functions like wifi and ethernet (did confirm HDMI works). here's a link to the product https://system76.com/desktops/meerkat

Comment: Thanks Chris. I used a non-powered device to check the USB ports (I figured they may be functioning for data, but not providing power), and all ports managed to provide at least some power (I didn't measure it).